# Image uploaded but database not updated (Update data with image in Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have make feature to update profile. The table is User HasOne DetailUser so every single user have 1 detail user. Everything works fine, except the photo update.
When i was trying to update the photo, photo was succesfully update into storage in public but the database not updated. Maybe somebody could help me. Thanks...

[image: Database DetailUser]
[image: Public Folder]

1. Controller

   public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request_profile, UpdateDetailUserRequest $request_detail_user)
   {
   $data_profile = $request_profile->all();
   $data_detail_user = $request_detail_user->all();

   ```
    // save to user 
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first(); 
    $user->name = $request_profile->input('name');

    // save to detail user 
    if($user->save()) {
        $detail_user = DetailUser::find($user->detail_user->id);
        $detail_user = DetailUser::where('id', $user->detail_user->id)->first();

        // delete old file from storage
        if (isset($data_detail_user['photo'])) {
            $data = 'storage/'. $detail_user['photo'];
            if (Storage::exists($data)) {
                Storage::delete($data);
            } else {
                Storage::delete('storage/app/public'. $detail_user['photo']);
            }
        }

        // store file to storage
        if (isset($data_detail_user['photo'])) {
            $data_detail_user['photo'] = $request_detail_user->file('photo')->store(
                'assets/photo', 'public'
            );
        }

        $detail_user->role = $request_detail_user->input('role');
        $detail_user->contact_number = $request_detail_user->input('contact_number');
        $detail_user->biography = $request_detail_user->input('biography'); 
        $detail_user->save();
    }

    // save to experience
    $experience_user_id = ExperienceUser::where('detail_user_id', $detail_user['id'])->first();
    if (isset($experience_user_id)) {

        foreach ($data_profile['experience'] as $key => $value) {
            $experience_user = ExperienceUser::find($key);
            $experience_user->detail_user_id = $detail_user['id'];
            $experience_user->experience = $value;
            $experience_user->save();
        }

    } else {

        foreach ($data_profile['experience'] as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($value)) {
                $experience_user = new ExperienceUser;
                $experience_user->detail_user_id = $detail_user['id'];
                $experience_user->experience = $value;
                $experience_user->save();
            }
        }

    }

    toast()->success('Update has been success');

    return back();
   ```

   }
2. Blade view

   ```
                                        <div class="flex items-center mt-1">

                                            @if (auth()->user()->detail_user()->first()->photo)
                                                <img src="{{ asset('storage/assets/photo/'. auth()->user()->detail_user()->first()->photo) }}" alt="photo profile" class="w-16 h-16 rounded-full">
                                            @else
                                                <span class="inline-block w-16 h-16 overflow-hidden bg-gray-100 rounded-full">
                                                    <svg class="w-full h-full text-gray-300" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                        <path d="M24 20.993V24H0v-2.996A14.977 14.977 0 0112.004 15c4.904 0 9.26 2.354 11.996 5.993zM16.002 8.999a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                                            @endif

                                            <label for="choose" class="px-3 py-2 ml-5 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500">Choose File</label>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="old_photo" value="{{ auth()->user()->detail_user()->first()->photo }}">    
                                            <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="choose" name="photo" hidden>

                                            <a href="{{ route('member.delete.photo.profile') }}" type="button" class="px-3 py-2 ml-5 text-sm font-medium leading-4 text-red-700 bg-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-green-500" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete your photo?')">
                                                Delete
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        @if ($errors->has('photo'))
                                            <p class="text-red-500 mb-3 text-sm">{{ $errors->first('photo') }}</p>
                                        @endif

                                    </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing image value on database, update this:

```
if (isset($data_detail_user['photo'])) {
         $data_detail_user['photo'] = $request_detail_user->file('photo')->store(
             'assets/photo', 'public'
         );
    $detail_user->photo = $data_detail_user['photo']; //or some uniquely generated image name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error? If not, you're probably not storing all the values you used in the UpdateDetailUserRequest.

Could you also share the request codes?

---

UPDATED:

Thank you for sharing the request. Since you are validating photo, role, contact_number and biography. I would recommend to change the following.

Change:

```
$detail_user->role = $request_detail_user->input('role');
$detail_user->contact_number = $request_detail_user- >input('contact_number');
$detail_user->biography = $request_detail_user->input('biography'); 
$detail_user->save();
```

To:

```
$detail_user->save($request_detail_user->validated());
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, here the request 

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'photo' => [
                'nullable', 'file', 'image', 'max:1024',
            ],
            'role' => [
                'nullable', 'string', 'max:100',
            ],
            'contact_number' => [
                'required', 'regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/',
            ],
            'biography' => [
                'nullable', 'string', 'max:5000',
            ],
        ];
    }

Nothing fancy

Answer (score 0):

Check your `DetailUser` model, is column `photo` fillable?

try to add this in your Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 'photo', 'columnName', 'columnName'];
```

or

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

Comment: Already did, protected $fillable = [
        'users_id', 
        'photo', 
        'role',
        'contact_number',
        'biography',
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];